# WPF: Setting TextBlock Height to 0 when there is no text

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

`TextBlock` always occupies some height even if it doesn't contain any text. The height of the `TextBlock` is determined by the font size if no text is present, except in case when it is explicitly set by the user, of course. Is there a way to make the `TextBlock` size equal (0,0) if there is no text present (or to make it collapsed)? Thanks.

Note: I have created a converter that set's the `Visibility` property of the `TextBlock` to `Collapsed` if there is no text, but I was wondering if the same or similar solution is possible without any converter or code-behind coding, i.e. to make it behave as explained only by using XAML.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Ah that's so easy! I should have seen it. Thanks!